# How to pass multiple parameters to vuex getters?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

In a vue.js component (using vuex), I have:

```
computed: {...
    filtered () {
      return this.withFilters(obj1, obj2)
```

with `withFilters` a getter to define in the store. But how in the store can I get the arguments passed to `withFilters` and define this getter accordingly? For a 1-argument function I would have simply done something like

```
withFilter: state => obj1 => { ...
```

For example:

```
withFilter: state => obj1 => {
 for (var k in obj1) {
  obj1[k] !== null ? console.log('Not null!') : console.log('Null!')
 }
}
```

Not sure how to do it with a 2-argument function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need to define the function returned by your `getter` with multiple arguments. For example

```js
getters: {
  withFilter (state) {
    return (obj1, obj2) => {
      // your code here
    }
  }
}
```

---

You could write this entirely with arrow functions but I think it looks messy (personal opinion)

```
withFilter: (state) => (obj1, obj2) => {
  // your code here
}
```

---

See the documentation on ES6 arrow functions and argument parentheses [here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_Syntax)

> // Parentheses are optional when there's **only one** parameter name:
>   (singleParam) => { statements }
>   singleParam => { statements }

Comment: thank you very much Phil. I tried exactly the second syntax you suggest but for some reason (did that late in the night so I was not in super good shape) it didn't work nor raise no error. Will try with your suggestion now I know that the syntax is correct.